# Pattern ?(-)+([0-9])

Tags: regex, bash

I saw this expression in a tutorial which says that it is an expression to match an integer.

I can't understand how is this matching an integer and also did not understand the used of `( )` to cover `-` and `[0-9]`. I understand that `?` is for 0 or 1 occurrence of a character [0-9] is for any digit once. How can I understand the rest of the part?

Comment: Show some context and link to the original tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a regular expression. It is an "extended glob" pattern, which is an optional facility in Bash, and also available in the Korn shell. In Bash, you enable it with `shopt -s extglob` and [read about it in the manual.](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC36)

See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob

Answer (score 1):

The `?(-)` means one or zero occurrences of `-` so this pattern handles negative integers.

The `+([0-9])` means one or more occurrences of a digit; this patterns handles integers of any length.

The parentheses are wrapped around the elements that the `+` and `?` operators are supposed to affect.

Comment: Do you have any reference to read this style of writing patterns ? Is it regular expression style?  If I had to write one or more occurrences of a digit I would have written [0-9]+ .

Comment: Nope, I have no reference to this style whatsoever, but it looks like 20 seconds looking at a regex cheat sheet mixed with math experience with parentheses. on the part of the author. -?[0-9]+ is the regex I'd be using.

Comment: That looks like an [extended glob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) pattern to me. They have the same expressive power as standard regular expressions, but the syntax is very different.